# Leaflet: TypeError L.markerClusterGroup is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openstreetmap

I found this problem on stackoverflow but answers don't work in my application.

If I tried `var cluster = L.markerClusterGroup()` I had error

> `L.markerClusterGroup()` is not a function

or `var cluster = new L.markerClusterGroup()` I had error

> `L.markerClusterGroup()` is not a constructor

I include css and script in my index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- Cluster -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should either write `var cluster = L.markerClusterGroup()` (this is the factory function) or write `var cluster = new L.MarkerClusterGroup()` (with capital M we address the class). Since the factory function is not working I am assuming something is wrong with your js: do you see any javascript errors in your browser's javascript console?

Comment: ```TypeError: L.markerClusterGroup is not a function
    at new StreetMapProvider (streetmap-provider.ts:87)
    at MapDirectiveController.initMap (map.directive.controller.ts:128)
    at map.directive.controller.ts:114
    at angular.min.js:163
    at e (angular.min.js:48)
    at angular.min.js:51```  it is my console

Comment: Is that the first error? Or maybe check the order your javascript files are loaded? Maybe this code is not waiting till document is ready, and then the order is more important. You can easily check in the console if `L.markerClusterGroup` is defined or not?

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem..No matter where I put the script in the html file I receive that error. Have you figured it out @lorke?